# Getting File Attributes with XMLReader in C#

Tags: c#, xmlreader

I used the XMLReader format:

---

```
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("batch.xml");
while (xmlReader.Read())
{
    //Keep reading
    if (xmlReader.Name.Equals("Keyword") && (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element))
    {
        // get attribute from the Xml element here
        string keywords = xmlReader.GetAttribute("name"); 
    }
}
```

How do I cast "keywords" as a String[]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

If your XML has a single `name` attribute that contains multiple keywords, call [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx), like this:

```
string[] keywords = xmlReader.GetAttribute("name").Split(' ');
```

If you have multiple `name` attributes or `Keyword` elements, create a `List<string>` and fill it up in a loop, like this:

```
List<string> keywords = new List<string>();
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("batch.xml");
while (xmlReader.Read()) {
    //Keep reading
    if (xmlReader.Name.Equals("Keyword") && (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element))
        keywords.Add(xmlReader.GetAttribute("name")); 
}
```

If you really need a `string[]`, you can call `keywords.ToArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a `XmlReader`, you can't have all nodes at once. You need to create a `List<string>` collection, populate and return it.